# Navigating animation wp8 no silverlight

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

If I am using the Frame.Navigate,it crosses over from one page to an another. But there is a type of animation between the crossing over.

What should I write to not have these animations?

Answer (score 0):

In App.xaml.cs you will find RootFrame_FirstNavigated method. Here default animation is being set. you can set `rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;` to remove page navigation animation.